No session tickets with BoringSSL
When experimenting with BoringSSL and Wireshark, I noticied that there were no session tickets exchanged after the handshake and I could not understand why.
The setup I used is the following :

I cloned BSSL repo (https://github.com/google/boringssl) at the latest commit 84845ad316e4326ae47bda8483cce660c1d6c05e
I built it with :
cmake -GNinja -B build
ninja -C build


I tested handshake with ./bssl server -accept 45102 and ./bssl client -connect 127.0.0.1:45102 and exported the TLS keys with SSLKEYLOGFILE flag to analyze the handshake in Wireshark

And what I see is
Client -> Server : Client Hello
Server -> Client : Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Extensions, Certificate, Certificate Verify, Finished
Client -> Server : Change Cipher Spec, Finished

Then nothing else, no session tickets are sent by the server. Did I do something wrong, should ticket be enabled in BoringSSL ?
